# Question about climbing in "A Line Across the Sky"

Tags: climbing, trad-climbing

I've been watching "A Line Across the Sky" which is a short-ish movie about Tommy Caldwell and Alex Honnold doing the Fitz Roy traverse.

During which Tommy Caldwell mentions Alex doing a 1000 and 2000 foot pitch up the North wall. I can't understand how this is possible? I assume he's not climbing without a rope but how does this work, like logistically.

Comment: Why assume he's not climbing without a rope? Have you seen Free Solo?

Comment: Lol because Tommy Caldwell is there and you can see the rope :p

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In his book "The Push" he describes this a bit. Most of the time they were using a [running belay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simul_climbing) which means they were climbing at the same time with some pieces of protection in between them to avoid a deadly fall. This technique allows to climb very long "pitches" with a normal length rope. Once the leader runs out of gear, he makes a belay and belays the second up. Then they hand over the gear or switch leads.

**A note of caution:**
Running belays are an advanced technique that should not be used if there is any realistic possibility of a fall. This is a safer alternative to going ropeless not an alternative to a proper belay pitch by pitch

Comment: Same thing as "simul-climbing", right?

Comment: Yes it is the same thing, just a different name